# Can we avoid using one hot encoding on a categorical data which has only 2 unique values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using an MLP Classifier. There are around 4-5 categorical attributes (such as Gender(Male/Female), Smoking(Yes/No), Diabetes(Yes/No), Hypertension(Yes/No)).

Do I necessarily need to use one hot encoding on all these features before using a neural network classifier? I don't have a lot of training data (only 130 samples).

Can I just get away with Label Encoding these attributes?

Comment: Read the accepted answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9443/when-to-use-one-hot-encoding-vs-labelencoder-vs-dictvectorizor)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, that will be enough. There is no gain in using one hot in this case.